# How come this vim macro doesn't work?

Tags: vim, macros

I've got a file that looks roughly like the following:

```
field :t, :type => String, :as => :timestamp
field :b, :type => String, :as => :test

index({ :t => 1 })
index({ :b => 1 })
```

I put my cursor on line 4, and record the following macro:

/:`<CR>`viwyma?field :`ctrl-r`0,`<CR>`$F:lviwy`aviwpj^

So search for a colon, go there, select the whole word (`t` in this case), create a mark on `a`, search backwards for field followed by a colon, the word in register 0 (`t`), then a comma. Go to the end of the line, go one character to the left, select the whole word, yank it, go back to the `a` mark, select the whole word, paste what I just yanked (`timestamp`), then go to the next line and to the first non-whitespace character (so I can run the macro again right away).

After that, line 4 is what I expect, `index({ :timestamp => 1 })`
Then, I try running the macro again, and line 5 becomes `index({ :: => 1 })`

Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I had installed vim-hardtime to make movement slower. I had assumed it would be disabled for macros but it turns out that's not the case.